# How to get xml node in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the cost node from an xmldocument, but I can't figure out how to set proper xpath expression. Here's my c# code:

```
XmlNode n = reportFields.SelectSingleNode(field[1].Trim());
```

field[1] is my xpath, a following string:

```
"    /Report/Tablix6/RowGroup_Collection/RowGroup/@Cost"
```

and that's part of innerXml property of reportFields:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Report Name=\"Sample\">
<Tablix6>
    <RowGroup_Collection>
        <RowGroup Cost=\"1199\" />
    </RowGroup_Collection>
</Tablix6>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

After executing this code n is null.

EDIT2: Here's the updated version of xmlDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="Telephony http://serverName" 
Name="Telephony" 
Textbox1="Telephony total cost" 
Textbox6="Updated: 2010-4" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="Telephony">
<Tablix6>
    <RowGroup_Collection>
        <RowGroup CostSEK="13.908239364624" /> 
    </RowGroup_Collection>
</Tablix6>
```

Comment: Do you really have those spaces in the `XPath`?

Comment: Yes, that's why I use trim().

Comment: What happens when you use this?

Comment: It gets trimmed properly: "/Report/Tablix6/RowGroup_Collection/RowGroup/@CostSEK"

Comment: Please explain what _is_ happening? What does `n` contain after that line of code? Is it the expected node? Something else?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the complete (but as small as possible) XML document, so that we can try to repro the problem. I strongly suspect that the XML document is in a default namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve it. Turns out I had to create a namespace and modify my XPath string to reflect that:

XPath:

```
ns:Report/ns:Tablix6/ns:RowGroup_Collection/ns:RowGroup/@CostSEK
```

C#:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(reportFields.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", "Telephony");
XmlNode n = reportFields.SelectSingleNode(field[1].Trim(), namespaces);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
XmlNode n = reportFields.SelectSingleNode("/Report/Tablix6/RowGroup_Collection/RowGroup").Attributes["Cost"];
```

You can then access the value of the node with n.Value, so

```
Console.Writeline(n.Value);
```

Should output "1199"

Comment: I can't do it that way, the xpath is taken from a file and it must be flexible enough to fetch attribute of any name without splitting the xpath string.

Comment: Okay, I tried this solution just to check if it would work, but I still get null.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
object attr = reportFields.SelectSingleNode(field[1].Trim()).Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"//Report/Tablix6/RowGroup_Collection/RowGroup/@Cost"
```

I can mistake, but i think that will be better if XPath expression will starting with double slash "//"

Comment: Should not be needed here: the first `/` already starts searching from the root. A `//` starts searching "anywhere below the root".